# About Flutter Firestore Rest Api Json Output

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rest

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "name": "projects/xxxxx/databases/(default)/documents/blogs/Hao5IboeA6b7ySlmx0qN",
            "fields": {
                "imgUrl": {
                    "stringValue": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxx/o/blogImages%2F72H566888.jpg?alt=media&token=75b75deb-69a3-4019-a82e-335a2d72b52e"
                },
                "authorName": {
                    "stringValue": "iki"
                },
                "title": {
                    "stringValue": "dd"
                },
                "desc": {
                    "stringValue": "ee"
                }
            },
            "createTime": "2020-10-31T08:57:46.799862Z",
            "updateTime": "2020-10-31T08:57:46.799862Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

I am using Firebase Firestore Rest Api. I have the output in json format like above. I created my model using Json to dart. My model is as follows.

```
class Model {
  List<Documents> documents;

  Model({this.documents});

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['documents'] != null) {
      documents = new List<Documents>();
      json['documents'].forEach((v) {
        documents.add(new Documents.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.documents != null) {
      data['documents'] = this.documents.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Documents {
  String name;
  Fields fields;
  String createTime;
  String updateTime;

  Documents({this.name, this.fields, this.createTime, this.updateTime});

  Documents.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    fields =
        json['fields'] != null ? new Fields.fromJson(json['fields']) : null;
    createTime = json['createTime'];
    updateTime = json['updateTime'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    if (this.fields != null) {
      data['fields'] = this.fields.toJson();
    }
    data['createTime'] = this.createTime;
    data['updateTime'] = this.updateTime;
    return data;
  }
}
......
```

**return jsonModel.map((item) => model.fromJson(item)).toList();** I returned it as but in FutureBuilder it comes as snapshot.data[index].documents.

How do I access the imgUrl, authorName, title, desc fields? I am having difficulty with this kind of mixed json output. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a nested structure listView, and you access to field models.

First way:

```
 return FutureBuilder<List<Document>>(
  future: getDocuments(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Document>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return buildListView(snapshot.data[index].documents);
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Text("error");
    }
  },
);
```

And you do sub inner method then draw.

```
 ListView buildListView(List<Documents> documents) {
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
    title: Text(documents[index].name),
    leading: Text(documents[index].fields.imgUrl.stringValue),
    subtitle: Text(documents[index].fields.desc.stringValue),
  ),
);
```

2.You could be convert list to list model with list expand functions.

```
  Future<List<Document>> getDocuments() async {
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 100));
return dummyItems;
  }

  Future<List<Documents>> getFieldsOnly() async {
final response = await getDocuments();
return response.expand((f) => f.documents).toList();
  }
```

Now, it's all done. You can [look at this repo](https://github.com/VB10/stack-over-help-flutter) for more details(lib/fire-store-document)

Comment: Firestore rest api get isteği attığımda aşağıdaki uyarıyı alıyorum.
type 'Document' is not a subtype of type. 'FutureOr<List<Document>>

When I run it in debug mode it comes up as Map. I return model.from as Json (jsonModel). I think my fault is here.

Comment: @Gurkan T Has the answer posted here helped you? Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: @MrTech yes it continues.